# How to tweak this melee script to be more responsive?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed this video to get a damage script : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSeE7u8Cs-I&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKiaTYwyayb8-L7D6bdiaHzc&index=11

The problem is, it's for a gun and for some reason even when the raycast is dead ahead sometimes the knife hit won't register. Is there any way to maybe just make it so that anything a unit in front of me takes damage on click/attack?

This is the current code I have:

````
void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Attack"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Poke());
        }
        else
        {

        }

        IEnumerator Poke()
        {
            RaycastHit knife;
            //this line was causing weird delay but I can't remember 100% what it was for and if it's still needed
            //isAttacking = true;
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out knife))

                {
                    knife.transform.SendMessage("DamageZombie", DamageAmount, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                animator.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
                animator.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
            }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool isAttacking = false;

void Start() {
    animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Attack")) {
        StartCoroutine(Poke());
    }
}

IEnumerator Poke() {
    if(!isAttacking){
        isAttacking = true;
        RaycastHit knife;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out knife)) {
            knife.transform.SendMessage("DamageZombie", DamageAmount, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
        animator.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
        animator.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
        isAttacking = false;
    }
}
```

Also have in mind that [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) may use [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) to detect objects, if nothing works, take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are probably hitting some other collider, some GameObject that doesn't have any component attached that has a method called `DamageZombie`.

There are multiple ways to limit the Raycast to specific targets:

1. [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) takes additional parameters

   > **maxDistance**
   >   
   >  The max distance the ray should check for collisions.
   >
   > **layerMask**
   >   
   > A Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore Colliders when casting a ray.

   So putting your target enemies on a specific [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) you can already limit the `Raycast` to only hit these and only when they are close enough:

   ```
   // Adjust here which layer(s) you want to hit via the Inspector
   public LayerMask targetLayers;

   ...

   if (Physics.Raycast(new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward), out var hit, 1f, (int)targetLayers))
   {
       // Do something
   }
   ```

   So this already filters the raycast and only hits the **first** object found within the range of `1` unit and only on the layer(s) configured in `targetLayers`.
2. As you said you wanted to `hit everything` you can actually use [`Physics.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) and then iterate through all hits

   ```
   var hits = Physics.RaycastAll(new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward), 1f, targetLayers);
   foreach(var hit in hits)
   {
       // Do something
   }
   ```

   Now this basically does the same as before but now hits **every** object within a range of `1` unit and on the layer(s) configured in `targetLayers`.
3. Using [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) you can limit even further and check after the Raycast what you have hit.

   ```
   foreach(var hit in hits)
   {
       if(!hit.CompareTag("Zombie")) continue;

       // Do something
   }
   ```

---

Finally in general do **NOT** use `SendMessage`! It is extremely inefficient and insecure .. you will never know if the object you are hitting even has a component implementing such a method at all ... or if you changed this string in every place after renaming the method ...

Rather actually get the component you want to hit!

```
var damageScript = hit.GetComponent<YOURSCRIPT>();
if(damageScript)
{
    damageScript.DamageZombie(DamageAmount);
}
```